# How to Extract Strings, Methods, and API Calls with Androguard

Tags: python, apk, androguard

I've been trying to achieve a functionality similar to what's available in the Androguard GUI, where you can extract strings, methods, and API calls from APKs. How can I do that programmatically?

```py
from androguard.core.bytecodes import apk
from androguard.core.bytecodes import dvm

a = apk.APK('app.apk')

# Load the DEX file
d = dvm.DalvikVMFormat(a.get_dex())

# Iterate through the methods
for method in d.get_methods():
    print(method.get_name(), method.get_descriptor())
```